# View pager inside a drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to have a drawer which is always open with a list of options(drawer list). The content has a view pager with fragments.

When I swipe from right to left or left to right on the **content frame** it should swipe the view pager fragments according to the swipe direction with the drawer open or close state as it is.

When i swipe the **drawer** from right to left it should dismiss.

So basically I want the view pager swipe enabled even when the drawer is open.

Is this possible and how can it be achieved.

Comment: How will you be able to tell the difference between a drawer-close gesture and a view pager swipe gesture? Also, are you sure a ViewPager inside a drawer is the best way to go?

Comment: IMHO, it is misunderstanding of this UI pattern. Navigation Drawer is a top level menu. It overlaps all of your content so you should not be able to do something while drawer is open. Drawer should not interfere with viewpager in terms of touch events. Maybe you should consider some other UI pattern for that, some Sliding Panel or similar.